# Functional minimization

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let $F(u) = -\int_0^1u\,dx$ and $H(u)= \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(u')^2}\,dx-A$ for some $A \gt 1$. If we have to minimize $F(u)$ in $C^1$ such that on the interval $[0,1]\:, u(0)=u(1)=0$, subject to $H(u)=0$.

What is would be the intuitive geometric interpretitation of this problem? what could one expect to be the optimal solution without actually solving for it explicitly?

Im trying to undertand this intuitively so any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What is u, what is F...??

Comment: @DonAntonio pardon my carelessness, i fixed it

Comment: I don't think so, @bobdylan: if you don't specify anything, then it is trivially true that $$F(u):=-\int\limits_0^1 u\,dx=-u$$ if $\,u\,$ is a constant wrt $\,x\,$...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H(u)=0$ means that length of the admissible curves is fixed at some $A>1$.

Minimizing $-\int_0^1 u\,dx$ is equivalent to maximizing $\int_0^1 u\,dx$, the area below the graph.

So you are looking for the function with maximal area below its graph, s.t. having its graph's length fixed at $A$.

I have not solved this explicitly, but you can get a rough idea by drawing. It should be symmetric about the point $x={1 \over 2}$